# How to add a string onto a value when storing that value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to add a string to the end of a value, but I get this error:

```
stored_data[kilometer_mile + ' Kilometers'] = (user_input1 + ' Miles')
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

So basically, all I want to know is can I add a string to a value? Or is it not an option. As it worked when I added a string to the Key part of the dictionary.
This is the code:

```
# Converting Kilometers to miles
kilometer_mile = input("Kilometers To Miles: ")
user_input1 = ((float(kilometer_mile) * 0.6213712))
print(f"{kilometer_mile} Kilometers = {user_input1} Miles")
stored_data[kilometer_mile + ' Kilometers'] = (user_input1 + ' Miles')
```

Comment: Where are you confused?  `user_input1` is a float; you're trying to "add" a string to it.  If you want a string result, then you have to convert `user_input1` to string first.  We expect you to look up the error message before you post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used f strings in your code before. Why not use it again?

```
kilometer_mile = input("Kilometers To Miles: ")
user_input1 = ((float(kilometer_mile) * 0.6213712))
print(f"{kilometer_mile} Kilometers = {user_input1} Miles")
stored_data[f'{kilometer_mile} Kilometers'] = (f'{user_input1} Miles')
```

Btw, your error was caused because you were doing something like the following

```
print(10+'.00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a string before concatenating.

```
stored_data[kilometer_mile + ' Kilometers'] = (str(user_input1) + ' Miles')
```